# Statistics probability - finding the exact distribution of X

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

So I'm stuck on finding the most efficient way to approach this homework problem.

In a certain population, 15% of the people have Rh-negative blood. A blood bank serving this population receives 100 blood donors on a particular day.

a. Let X be the number of donors in the sample with Rh-negative blood. What is the
exact distribution of X?

So I'm assuming in order to solve this question, I'm supposed to do something like:

P(x=0) = ( 100 C 0 )*(15/100)^0 (85/100)^100

P(x = 1) = (100 C 1) *(15/100)^1*(85/100)^99

P(x = 2) = (100 C 2)*(15/100)^2 (85/100)^(98)

....

But that seems like an awful lot of steps for one question. Is there a quicker way to answer this question wihout using combinations? Should I not be using binomial distribution?

Update: After doing some searching I found a thread with a similar question. Someone commented using poisson distribution and I was wondering if that would work? [Exact and approximate probability distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98573/exact-and-approximate-probability-distribution)

Comment: It looks like you already know the answer but don't know how to write it down succinctly.  The trick is just to use a variable in your answer, like so: $P(X=x)=\binom{100}{x} 0.15^x 0.85^{100-x}$.

Comment: In words, $X$ has a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=100$ and $p=0.15$

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Comment in Answer format to permit a graph.

Assuming that participation does not change with blood
type, the number with Rh negative blood will be
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 100, p=0.15).$

In R statistical software a binomial PDF is called `dbinom`, so the formula in @ sasquire' comment is as
shown in the code below, used to make the figure.

```
x = 0:30;  PDF = dbinom(x, 100, .15)
plot(x, PDF, type="h", lwd=2)
abline(h = 0, col="green2")
```

[image]

Because $P(X > 30) \approx 0,$ that part of the graph is not shown.